# Using pdfgrep to search for sentences containing specific words

Tags: grep

For my statistics exam, I would like to be able to search for sentences containing specific words in our textbook (we have as a pdf file). I've downloaded the command line tool pdfgrep (grep for pdf files)

An example:

I would like to search for a sentence containing the two words "median" and "exponential"

I've tried:

```
pdfgrep "\..*median.*exponential\." book-IntroStatistics.pdf
```

But it does not seem to be working and just gives me large chunks of text.

Comment: Try `"[^?!.]*median[^?!.]*exponential[^?!.]*"`

Comment: Hm, then I get ` -bash: !.]*median[^?!.]*exponential[^?!.]*": event not found `

Comment: That is because of `!`, escape it. `'[^?\!.]*median[^?\!.]*exponential[^?\!.]*'`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pdfgrep '[^?\!.]*median[^?\!.]*exponential[^?\!.]*' book-IntroStatistics.pdf
```

The `[^?\!.]*` parts match any 0+ chars other than `?`, `!` and `.` chars.