# Select paragraph in pdf text using pdfgrep from specific word

Tags: regex, pdf, nsregularexpression, grepl

I'm starting with regular expressions, and I'm trying to select all paragraph that have two specific words(IDAILDA or 282610/SP) from pdf file that have more than 3000 pages.

If the paragraph have or **IDAILDA** or **282610/SP**, I have to select it.

Example:

Processo 1001959-75.2018.8.26.0028 - Divórcio Consensual - Dissolução - S.M.R.A.S. - Ofício e Mandado de Averbação
disponíveis para retirada pelo interessado (fls. 30/31). - ADV: **IDAILDA** APARECIDA GOMES (OAB **282610/SP**)

Processo 1002033-32.2018.8.26.0028 - Inventário - Inventário e Partilha - Maria das Graças de Souza Andrade - Jaqueline
de Souza Andrade - - Raquel de Souza Andrade - Aguarde-se o recolhimento do imposto causa mortis. - ADV: LUIZ GUSTAVO
CAVALHEIRO FERREIRA (OAB 240154/SP), ANTONIO AUGUSTO CALTABIANO ELYSEU (OAB 239669/SP)

Processo 0000995-65.2019.8.26.0028 (processo principal 1000841-98.2017.8.26.0028) - Cumprimento de sentença - Perdas
e Danos - Adriano Teixeira Guimarães - Silvestre Pelegrini Batista - VISTOS. Expeça-se guia de levantamento do valor depositado, intimando-se a
parte autora/exequente. Em seguida, transitada a presente em julgado e nada mais sendo requerido, arquivem-se os autos
com as cautelas devidas. P. R. I. C. - ADV: **IDAILDA** APARECIDA GOMES (OAB **282610/SP**), MARIA APARECIDA SOUSA GAY
MAROTTA (OAB 91666/SP), HUGO VALLE DOS SANTOS SILVA (OAB 181789/SP)

Following this logic, I should have the whole first and third paragraph as a answer for my request.

All paragraphs that I have to select, start with the word **Processo**, then I tried this code

```
pdfgrep 'Processo[^?\!.]*IDAILDA[^?\!.]*282610/SP[^?\!.]*' mypdf.pdf
```

But the answer for this request was void. So I tried only with the word **IDAILDA**:

```
pdfgrep '[^?\!.]*IDAILDA[^?!.]*' mypdf.pdf
```

It worked, but did not give back the all paragraph (of course). The problem is not in the pdf, but in the expression. Thanks in advance.

> [Using pdfgrep to search for sentences containing specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558552/using-pdfgrep-to-search-for-sentences-containing-specific-words)

Comment: If the paragraph should have either of them, try using an alternation `^Processo .*\b(?:IDAILDA|282610/SP)\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/sQFiFP/1

Comment: I saw that your expression worked in regex, but didn't work with pdfgrep. I code 
`pdfgrep -P '^Processo .*\b(?:IDAILDA|282610/SP)\b.*' mypdf.pdf`
But the answer still was void. The "-P" in the code is to use PCRE with pdfgrep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

`^(?=.*IDAILDA)^(?=.*282610\/SP)^Processo.*`

https://regex101.com/r/UCCFbQ/1

The first two parts of this pattern use negative lookahead to assert that from the beginning of the string, there's any number of characters followed by `IDAILDA`, then checks the same for `282610/SP`.

Then the pattern anchors back to the beginning to make sure it starts with `Processo` and matches everything after that.

Comment: I tried this pattern, but still nothing appeared. 
The code that I tried was 
`pdfgrep -P ^(?=.*IDAILDA)^(?=.*282610\/SP)^Processo.* mypdf.pdf ` 
and an error appeared "syntax error near unexpected token '('. 
Then I tried:
`pdfgrep -P "^(?=.*IDAILDA)^(?=.*282610\/SP)^Processo.*" mypdf.pdf ` 
and then nothing appeared...
I saw that your expression worked, but I think my problem is with the pdfgrep, not with the expression now. If you know something about pdfgrep, woud really help. Thank you so much! @CAustin